# Elasticsearch with query => 1 Doc with array of 2 values Return 2 hits

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I need help writing query.

doc in ES is
{ A: "A", B: ["1","2"] }

result from query should be: hits(2x)
{ A:"A" , B: "1"},
{ A:"A" , B: "2" }

is this possible?

Comment: If there is a single document stored in the index, a query will not be able to split it into two hits in the results. Maybe you can explain your use case in more details.

Comment: Yes there is only one doc in index. But in Client's gird I need to show data in 2 lines. I have everything working ( in client app I map all the values from array) the problem is pagination.

Comment: Yeah, that's something you need to handle client-side or denormalize and index two documents instead